# data argument can't be an iterator

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

When trying to execute the following code to create a dataframe from a csv file I get the following error.

**code:**

```
f = open(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/test.csv"))
data = pd.DataFrame(f)
```

**error:**

raise TypeError("data argument can't be an iterator")
TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator

why is this and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/test.csv"))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/test.csv"))
```